# Question about convergence in $H^1_0$

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

Please how to prove that if $u_n\rightarrow u$ on $H^1_0$ we have that $||u_n||\rightarrow ||u||$ ?

Please i need your help

Thank you

Comment: What does $\|u_n\|$ mean here?

Comment: the norm in $H^1_0$ $||u_n||^2=\int_{I} u'^2(t) dt$

Comment: In general, if $x_n \to x$ in a normed space, then the fact that $$\|x_n - x\| \to 0$$ implies that $\|x_n\| \to \|x\|$ by the triangle inequality (e.g. write $x = x - x_n + x_n$ and proceed).

Comment: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, convergence in the norm implies convergence of the norms; that is, if $x_n \to x$ in the norm, then $\|x_n\| \to \|x\|$. This follows from the reverse triangle inequality:

$$\Big|\|x_n\| - \|x\|\Big| \le \|x_n - x\| \to 0$$

Alternatively, apply the triangle inequality to $x = (x - x_n) + x_n$ to get that $$\|x\| \le \liminf_{n \to \infty} \|x_n\|$$

and to $x_n = x_n - x + x$ to get that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \|x_n\| \le \|x\|$.

Note that this doesn't have to do with the particular norm in use here.